# How to convert .epsf to .eps?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, eps

I'm looking for a method of converting .epsf to .eps for a publication I'm submitting. The submission site requires .eps (even though my understanding is that modern renderers should be able to read .epsf as well - the site is archaic, I have to upload all 100 images individually.) My co-author sent me the zipped files to upload (and now to convert) - I didn't make them myself. Further, the programs that made these images may exist on my co-authors computer but where is uncertain.

I've tried this in Mathematica 8 to reasonable but not full success - as in colored files become black and white, files with duplicate entries (as in Fig11a.eps and Fig11a.epsf both exist though they are different, it seems that the .eps is the background and the .epsf is the foreground layer) convert incorrectly. My attempt was to import the .epsf files to Mathematica and export them as .eps.

Also, I've using a middle man format - e.g. gif/tiff/png/jpg - with similar results. I haven't been able to find a program that's free (I assume photoshop could pull this off) that I could use - also I'd like to do it as a batch. A method that uses requires python/Mathematica or XP/Linux OS's would be fine. Thanks.

Comment: What version of Mma are you using? In version 8.01 I can import epsf files and export them to .eps, apparently without trouble.

Comment: I am not familiar with the .epsf format.  Can you direct me to a description?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to convert anything.  Encapsulated PostScript files can have both extensions (both EPS and EPSF).  If you publisher refuses to accept files with an EPSF extension just rename them to EPS.

Any processing/conversion you do on the files (using GhostScript, Mathematica, etc.) carries the risk of corrupting the graphics in some way.  But there's no need to do it.  Send them as they are or rename them if you prefer.

(If you have any doubt, you can check the [EPS Format Specification from 1992](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/5002.EPSF_Spec.pdf) which says that on the Macintish the recommended file extension is .epsf while on DOS it's .EPS)

Comment: There was random corruption which was a bit bothersome. I had noticed that I could change the filetype but didn't see a hard references to this being the case so thanks!My only followups

Comment: There was random corruption which was a bit bothersome. I had noticed that I could change the filetype but didn't see a hard references to this being the case so thanks!

For future ask-ers of the same question I will place the rename command I used here as well:

`Windows XP`
`C:[dir to folder with files]>ren *.epsf *.eps`